# Possible to stream video content from OneDrive into a VideoView?

Tags: android, onedrive

I was wondering if it is possible to stream a link of a OneDrive video to a VideoView? Would we first need to get the direct link of the file including the extension and load it into the VideoView or is there an easier way?

Comment: you got any solution John?